# Having trouble installing PHPUnit with PEAR Installer (Windows)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, installation, pear

I am trying to install `phpunit/PHPUnit`. I get something like below, I think the problem is that `Archive/Tar.php` is not found? I tried using the `--alldeps` switch and got the same error. Trying to install `pear install archive_tar` even gives the same error where `Archive/Tar.php` was not found!

```
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks>pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
downloading PHPUnit-3.5.5.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.5.5.tgz (116,148 bytes)
.........................done: 116,148 bytes

Warning: require_once(Archive/Tar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in PEAR\PackageFile.php on line
 303

Warning: require_once(Archive/Tar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\p
ear\PEAR\PackageFile.php on line 303

Call Stack:
    0.0051     531000   1. {main}() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\pearcmd.php:0
    0.3031    3490920   2. PEAR_Command_Common->run() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\pearcmd.php:305
    0.3031    3490920   3. PEAR_Command_Install->doInstall() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Command\Common.php:271

    0.3672    5387880   4. PEAR_Downloader->download() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Command\Install.php:661
   62.4850    8482968   5. PEAR_Downloader_Package->download() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Downloader.php:453
   62.4906    8488512   6. PEAR_Downloader_Package->_fromUrl() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Downloader\Package.p
hp:263
   63.1216    8490512   7. PEAR_PackageFile->fromAnyFile() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Downloader\Package.php:1
622
   63.1226    8490616   8. PEAR_PackageFile->fromTgzFile() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\PackageFile.php:483


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Archive/Tar.php' (include_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear')
in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\PackageFile.php on line 303

Call Stack:
    0.0051     531000   1. {main}() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\pearcmd.php:0
    0.3031    3490920   2. PEAR_Command_Common->run() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\pearcmd.php:305
    0.3031    3490920   3. PEAR_Command_Install->doInstall() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Command\Common.php:271

    0.3672    5387880   4. PEAR_Downloader->download() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Command\Install.php:661
   62.4850    8482968   5. PEAR_Downloader_Package->download() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Downloader.php:453
   62.4906    8488512   6. PEAR_Downloader_Package->_fromUrl() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Downloader\Package.p
hp:263
   63.1216    8490512   7. PEAR_PackageFile->fromAnyFile() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\Downloader\Package.php:1
622
   63.1226    8490616   8. PEAR_PackageFile->fromTgzFile() C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\PEAR\PackageFile.php:483

D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks>
```

**UPDATE**: I should say its on Windows, I have no problems installing on Ubuntu

Comment: How about "pear upgrade pear" and then trying phpunit?

Comment: I solved the problem my reinstalling PEAR, I think Archive_Tar should be installed with PEAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling PEAR, I think Archive_Tar should be installed with PEAR

Comment: Mark it as your answer dude :-)

Comment: This was the issue for me. Apparently PEAR doesn't always intall Archive_Tar correctly the first time. Simply running the go-pear.phar script again solved the issue.